# Can I find a breakdown of SO's developer survey for most popular language?

Tags: feature-request, survey-2019

I saw the developer survey saying that Java is the most popular language and I find myself a little credulous, to be honest. I have quite a few friends who are programmers (still less than 0.000000000000001% of developers, I know), but no one uses Java. I would really like to see that statistic broken down more ie. Gender, Geographic Region, Years Experience, etc. Is there anywhere I can see this data. The report I saw gave a very passing comment on what the most popular were, but nothing else.

Comment: Have you looked in the [data dump](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/21/public-data-release-of-stack-overflows-2019-developer-survey/?cb=1)?

Comment: I have not. Thnaks very much for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with the back-end thing (linked from [here](https://glitch.com/glimmer/post/discover-insights-explore-developer-survey-results-2019)) and came up with [this query](https://2019-stackoverflow-datasette.glitch.me/csv-data?sql=select+count%28rowid%29+as+count%2C+Country%2C+Gender+--rowid%2C+Respondent%2C+MainBranch%2C+Hobbyist%2C+OpenSourcer%2C+OpenSource%2C+Employment%2C+Country%2C+Student%2C+EdLevel%2C+UndergradMajor%2C+EduOther%2C+OrgSize%2C+DevType%2C+YearsCode%2C+Age1stCode%2C+YearsCodePro%2C+CareerSat%2C+JobSat%2C+MgrIdiot%2C+MgrMoney%2C+MgrWant%2C+JobSeek%2C+LastHireDate%2C+LastInt%2C+FizzBuzz%2C+JobFactors%2C+ResumeUpdate%2C+CurrencySymbol%2C+CurrencyDesc%2C+CompTotal%2C+CompFreq%2C+ConvertedComp%2C+WorkWeekHrs%2C+WorkPlan%2C+WorkChallenge%2C+WorkRemote%2C+WorkLoc%2C+ImpSyn%2C+CodeRev%2C+CodeRevHrs%2C+UnitTests%2C+PurchaseHow%2C+PurchaseWhat%2C+LanguageWorkedWith%2C+LanguageDesireNextYear%2C+DatabaseWorkedWith%2C+DatabaseDesireNextYear%2C+PlatformWorkedWith%2C+PlatformDesireNextYear%2C+WebFrameWorkedWith%2C+WebFrameDesireNextYear%2C+MiscTechWorkedWith%2C+MiscTechDesireNextYear%2C+DevEnviron%2C+OpSys%2C+Containers%2C+BlockchainOrg%2C+BlockchainIs%2C+BetterLife%2C+ITperson%2C+OffOn%2C+SocialMedia%2C+Extraversion%2C+ScreenName%2C+SOVisit1st%2C+SOVisitFreq%2C+SOVisitTo%2C+SOFindAnswer%2C+SOTimeSaved%2C+SOHowMuchTime%2C+SOAccount%2C+SOPartFreq%2C+SOJobs%2C+EntTeams%2C+SOComm%2C+WelcomeChange%2C+SONewContent%2C+Age%2C+Gender%2C+Trans%2C+Sexuality%2C+Ethnicity%2C+Dependents%2C+SurveyLength%2C+SurveyEase%0D%0Afrom+results+where+%22LanguageWorkedWith%22+like+%3Ap0+group+by+Country%2C+Gender+order+by+count+desc+limit+101+&p0=%25Java%3B%25).

It shows the number of responses from people who have worked with Java grouped by country and gender - you can break it down further by playing with the query.

The "languages worked with" field seems to be a semi-colon separated string, so I'm searching for `Java;` to avoid matching Javascript. This means that it's not catching responses where Java is the last or only language.  Please edit my post if you find a way to fix that :)

Here are the top 11 results, including the top country+gender combination where gender is not "Man":

```
count   Country Gender
6289    United States   Man
3522    India   Man
2386    Germany     Man
1514    United Kingdom  Man
1114    Canada  Man
894     France  Man
751     Brazil  Man
740     Italy   Man
707     Spain   Man
608     Netherlands     Man
597     United States   Woman
```

Comment: Very cool. Thanks. Interesting that in most nations, Java is more popular among Men, but in the United States, it is more popular among women. I love data!   Also, thanks for being careful with the javascript. I had assumed this was why 'Java' appeared the most popular. I know quite a few people that always refer to JS as Java so I assumed this was a major cause of that appearing more popular than it was. Tbh, I still assume some people might have said Java when they meant to put Java without knowning.

Comment: ^ Even then I put Java when I meant to put Javascript :(